# Assigning a type to a property that is a nested type of a Maybe type

Tags: typescript, graphql, typescript2.0, graphql-codegen

I'm trying to assign to a property a type generated by the `graphql-codegen` tool.  The type I'm trying to assign is a nested type.  Given the following type:

```
type SomeType = {
  someKey: Maybe<
    { __typename?: "OtherType" | undefined } & 
    { someNestedKey: ({ __typename?: "AnotherType" | undefined } & Pick<AnotherType, "prop1" | "prop2">)[] } 
  >
}
```

I need to be able to do:

```
myProperty: SomeType['someKey']['someNestedKey'] = []
```

However, the problem I'm running into is that the type of `someKey` is a `Maybe` type, so Typescript is complaining that there is no `someNestedKey` property on the `<Maybe { __typename?: "OtherType" | ...} & { someNestedKey: (...)[] }>` type (i.e., the type of `someKey`).

In Typescript, you can use the `!` method to state that you know for sure that the property value of a type that is union'ed with `undefined` and/or `null` does, in fact, exist in this case.  Is there a way to do something similar when assigning a type?

Since I'm using the `graphql-codegen` tool, I don't have control of these types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer in the documentation.  I need to use the `NonNullable` type.

```
myProperty: NonNullable<SomeType['someKey']>['someNestedKey'] = []
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out on this exact issue for 3 hours. Thank you!